# Скопировать из SSMS все поле типа varbinary

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

Необходимо как то получить полное значение большого файла в формате varbinary. Видимо в SSMS есть ограничение на количество выводимых символов в ячейке

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Да, ограничение есть. Именно чтобы не тянули гигабайты, куда не нужно. / Вам это значение куда нужно в конечном итоге поместить?

Comment: Если там в поле действительно тело файла - то FILESTREAM.